# aligning 2 divs side by side

Tags: css, html

I've seen a lot of these questions asked but none answered my question. I'm trying to align 2 divs side by side. The divs have the same class as they are pulled dynamically with php. I can't figure out how to align it! Here's the code:

```
<div class="holder">
<a href="#" class="item">
</a>
<a href="#" class="item">
</a>
</div>

.holder {
float:left;
width:40%;
margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
}

.item {
padding:7px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: I see only one div in your code.

Comment: If your `holder` container isn't wide enough to keep both elements aside then they break in lines maybe you can use `white-space`

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block`

```
.item {
padding:7px;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0 0 15px;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7ZqK5/)

or `display:inline`

```
.item {
padding:7px;
display:inline;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0 0 15px;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7ZqK5/1/)

Comment: <a> elements are displayed inline by default

Answer (score 1):

```
.holder {
  float:left;
  width:40%;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
}
.item {
  padding:7px;display:inline;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin:0 0 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3WZaf/